# Include CSRF token in Ajax calls with rails_ujs and Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I migrated to Webpacker and suddenly none of my Ajax calls worked.  I get

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
```

Which means the token is not included.

I can fix this by going over all calls and including it like this:

```
authenticity_token: $('[name="csrf-token"]')[0].content
```

which works.  However before it was working without that.  I believe rails/ujs is responsible for automatically adding it to all Ajax calls.

This is my application.js file in the packs dir:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("chartkick");
```

and this is in environments.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const babel =  require('./loaders/babel')

const webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery'
}));
```

Why is the token no longer automatically added?  Do I need to do something else to get it added to all Ajax calls?

Edit: Some example Ajax code as requested:

```
:coffee
  document.body.addEventListener 'click', ((evt) ->
    if evt.target.className.includes('room-blink')
      $.ajax(
        url: '/devices/' + evt.target.value + '/blink'
        type: 'patch'
      )
    return
    ), false
```

Edit2:

This is in the head of the application.haml in layouts:

```
= csrf_meta_tags
= csp_meta_tag
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
%link{:href => "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:300,400,400i,600,700&display=swap", :rel => "stylesheet"}/
= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```

Gemfile : https://pastebin.com/HjAWykAT
package.json : https://pastebin.com/LHbYJm0e

Comment: Can you show us the Ajax code?

Comment: Sure, I've edited the question to include it.

Comment: Where is that :coffee code rendered? In a view? If so, how are you exposing jQuery to the global scope?

Comment: Yes in a view.  jQuery is exposed through this line in environments.js: environment.plugins.append

Comment: ProvidePlugin does not expose jQuery to your view, that’s not how it works. Can you post more of your code? Are you still using the Rails asset pipeline? What’s in your application layout?

Comment: jQuery is working, if I type $('#page-container') in the console I get:
jQuery.fn.init [div#page-container.enable-page ...

I'm not using the asset pipeline anymore, completely migrated to Webpacker.  It's since then that I'm getting the CSRF issues.  I'll add the layouts part that is relevant.

Comment: What do you use to transpile coffeescript in the view? Gemfile and package.json will also be helpful.

Comment: I suspect the instance of jQuery in your view is not the same instance that’s imported via Webpack which would explain why it’s not enhanced by rails/ujs.

Comment: Thanks @rossta for your persistence.  I've added Gemfile and package.json to the question.  Is there any way I can verify your jQuery remark?

Comment: @rossta Some more info: when I trigger the ajax event from within a stimulus controller (I'm adding that too), then it works without having to set the token manually.

Comment: Re: stimulus, that would make sense assuming it’s for code bundled by Webpack. To test jQuery, try importing jQuery in Webpack, adding an attribute, e.g., `import $ from ‘jquery’; $.hello = ‘world’;`, then checking to see if it that attr is defined on $ within the browser console. If not, the instance of jQuery that’s globally available is not the same as the one in Webpack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209696/discussion-between-rept-and-rossta).